# SlideItMoo - if less than 3 elements hide controls

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'm using the SlideItMoo-Script on a website. Normally there are displayed 3 items to "scroll" trough, on click the script slides to the next three items/elements.

It can be that there are only 2 items to display. If that's the case I'd like to hide the controls for forward and backward.

So far I've been trying it like this:

```
if ('.SlideItMoo_element') <= 3 {
jQuery('.SlideItMoo_forward').css({ "display" : "none" });
});
```

But this didn't work. The 2nd line itself without the if-statement hides the forward-control as wanted.

I tried several "variable-names" like SlideItMoo_items, SlideItMoo_element and itemsSelector, but nothing worked for me.

This is the HTML-Output I get:

```
<!--thumbnails slideshow begin-->
<div id="SlideItMoo_outer">
<div class="SlideItMoo_back"><!--slide back button--></div>
<div id="SlideItMoo_inner">
<div id="SlideItMoo_items"><div class="Thurs"><div class="SlideItMoo_element">

<div class="heute">
<h3>18.30h</h3>
<h2>Hatha Yoga</h2>
<div class="info">Info ABC</div>
für Einsteiger
</div><!--Ende "heute"-->

<a class="startseite" href="./hatha-yoga.html" title="Hatha Yoga"> </a>

</div> <!--Ende "SlideItMoo_element"-->

 </div>
<div class="clear"></div></div>
<div> </div>
</div>
<div class="SlideItMoo_forward"><!--slide forward button--></div>
</div>
<!--thumbnails slideshow end-->
```

Does anyone have a tip for me how to solve this?

EDIT:

OK, as i can't get it to work I thought it would be helpful to count the number of the divs that get displayed. After some research I found this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var Divcount = jQuery(".SlideItMoo_element");
    for (i = 0; i < Divcount.length; i++) {
        alert(jQuery(Divcount[i]).length);
    }
});
```

But the problem is, that an alert pops up for each "SlideItMoo_element", but it always shows the number "1". So the value of "i" doesn't change, it does not add one up for each found "SlideItMoo_element"...

Comment: This looks a bit messy with jQuery and Mootools being mixed like this... do you have a live link to get a better picture?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I made it with this code:

```
var Divcount = jQuery(".SlideItMoo_element");
for (i = 0; i < Divcount.length; i++) {
     if (jQuery(Divcount).length <= 3 ) {
         jQuery('.SlideItMoo_forward').css({ "display" : "none" });
         jQuery('.SlideItMoo_back').css({ "display" : "none" });
     }
}
```